# How to create a plain background in UISegmented Control in iPhone

Tags: iphone, background, gallery, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created scroll view and set the Segmented control as subview. If i scroll the segments and it moves horizontally. I have set,

```
 segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
```

I got an output like this,

[Image-1 http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3d98eda2bd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3d98eda2bd.png)

But i want to plain background with the segments like this,
[Image-2 http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/efe195f809.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/efe195f809.png)

So is it possible to create a segments with plain background. Please guide me and if it is not possible please give me some alternate suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Pugal

Answer (score 0):

```
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray
                                   arrayWithArray:temp]];

[segment setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 30.0)];

[segment setSegmentedControlStyle: UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

[segment setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

if you set TintColor , your UISegmentedControl style have to be "UISegmentedControlStyleBar"
other style will be not work!